# Scrabble premium word score question

Tags: scoring, scrabble

In the following scenario, does a double word premium apply to both words made on the same turn? Player 1 plays the word "book". Player 2 plays the word "shot", placing the "s" on a double word score space, and also forming the word "books".

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From the [rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules),

> When two or more words are formed in the same play, each is scored. The common letter is counted (**with full premium value**, if any) for each word.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm taking the rule too literally, as it says that the "common letter" is counted with full premium value for both words. Can I interpret that as saying the premium applies to both words (not just the "common letter")?

Comment: The premium value of the letter in your example is to multiply the points for the word built. Or as the rule I quoted says, each of the words built. There is nothing to support a theory that a Double Word square sometimes acts as a Double Letter square